# Can't get categorys in enhanced ecommerce

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I'm trying to figure out how google enhanced ecommerce tracking works together with google tag manager. I have the following json I'm trying to send with `ProductClickEvent`:

```
dataLayer.push({
  event: 'ProductClickEvent',
  eventCategory: 'Link',
  eventAction: 'Product Name',
  ecommerce: {
    click: {
      actionField: {list: 'TopProducts', action: 'click'},
      products: [
        {
          name: 'Product Name',
          category: 'category/another category',
          id: '8722095',
          position: 1,
          price: '5.85'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

but when I look at the overview and click on and try to get category list (enhanced ecommerce) I get 'Not set' on all the products.

Do I have to add something to tag manager to hook this up?

Comment: after you click the product, type `dataLayer` in the console and inspect the object that you you're pushing. does it have a value for category?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code, with the colon at the end, instead of a semi-colon. (But I presume you would have picked that up already, so not sure if that is the problem.)

Comment: @Blexy: I'm running the debug tool with google tag manager and the code above is what I get in the summary and "Message pushed to Data Layer"

Comment: It's just a copy typo @nyuen thanks :)